# PowerShell не реагирует после запуска локального сервера

Tags: pycharm, fastapi, uvicorn

Запускаю локальный сервер, вводя в терминал Pycharm команду `uvicorn main:app`. Все отлично, но после этого терминал не реагирует ни на что. Если я добавляю функцию, мне приходится завершать с помощью `CTRL+C` и заново запускать той же командой. А я хочу обновить. Подскажите, как?